# Find all x so that Ax = 0 using dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
        A= \pmatrix{
        1 & 2 \\
        2 & 4 \\
        }, \quad
x =\pmatrix{a \\b}
$$

I know that each row vector of $A$ is supposed to be perpendicular to $x$, which means the dot product is $0$. I took this to mean $1a + 2b = 0$ and $2a+ 4b = 0$, but the only $a,b$ I see that would solve this is $a=b=0$. Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The two equations are the same.  Thus, you have one degree of freedom.  If $a$ is fixed, then $b = -\frac{a}{2}$ solves the equations.  Thus, the solution set is $\{ (a,-\frac{a}{2}) \}$

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrive at the solution?

Comment: @Sleyah You have two equations. But, multiplying $1a+2b=0$ by $2$, you get $2a+4b=0$, which is exactly the second one, so these two equations are actually the same. So, let us get back to the first one: $1a+2b=0$. Subtract $a$ from both sides and you get $2b = -a$. Divide by $2$ and $b = -a/2$.